# Class A is not assignable from B. Please revise Envers annotations applied to B type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I had the exceptionlike that:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Class rf.dom.billing.model.meta.BaseEntity is not assignable from rf.dom.billing.model.contractor.UpiIdentificator. Please revise Envers annotations applied to rf.dom.billing.model.contractor.UpiIdentificator type.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204)
        at rf.dom.billing.contractor.Application.main(Application.java:25)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Class rf.dom.billing.model.meta.BaseEntity is not assignable from rf.dom.billing.model.contractor.UpiIdentificator. Please revise Envers annotations applied to rf.dom.billing.model.contractor.UpiIdentificator type.
        at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.reader.AuditedPropertiesReader.checkSuperclass(AuditedPropertiesReader.java:231)
        at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.reader.AuditedPropertiesReader.readAuditOverrides(AuditedPropertiesReader.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.reader.AuditedPropertiesReader.read(AuditedPropertiesReader.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.reader.AnnotationsMetadataReader.getAuditData(AnnotationsMetadataReader.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.EntitiesConfigurator.configure(EntitiesConfigurator.java:65)
        at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.doInitialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.initialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:118)
        at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.produceAdditionalMappings(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:296)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1202)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1233)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
```

what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@AuditOverride(forClass = BaseEntity.class, isAudited = true)
```

was appiled to the class which wasn't extending this `BaseEnitity` class (i.e. class B wasn't actually extending class B, but had `@AuditOverride` which isn't needed at all).

After removing it everything worked fine